# Distinct and Count in table

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct

Need to write a MySQL query to check the database table and fetch distinct values and its count.

[image]

```
select distinct(fruits), count(distinct(fruits)) from table;
```

Will this suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a `group by`

```
select fruits, count(fruits) as fc
from table
group by fruits
order by fc desc;
```

Comment: he needs distinct fruits not fruits.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan the `group by` will give him a distinct list - it's the same thing.

Comment: sorry didn't see your group by

Comment: @ bon Thanks. If I need them to be  order by count desc then??

Comment: yup you may add any order that you prefer :)